# knockout.js - IE -7 css class Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, knockout.js

Here is a funny little issue i've come across with
dynamically setting the class for a array of divs.

Using Knockout.js i'm assigning the classes used via the 'attr' binding.

This works well in all browsers i've tested except IE-7 (Not worried about IE-6 etc)

I have an jsfiddle example highlighting the [issue here](http://jsfiddle.net/VVuGh/10/)

In the example the static (top row) should match the bottom one (ko generated)
In IE-7 i'm just seeing the broadest css selector color (Silver)

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/VVuGh/11/ - the title is now set to the same as the class. If you hover over the dynamic squares you can see that the title is being set correctly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IE7 requires that you set `className` instead of `class`.

For instance, this works in IE7 *and* other browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/VVuGh/14/

```
<div data-bind='attr: { "class": classes, "className": classes }'></div>
```

However, support for this IE7 quirk should ideally not be in your HTML. Inside knockout.js would be a better place, though I know nothing about the library to be able to make such a recommendation.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that answer!

Answer (score 0):

If your class name can't be determined when you generate the template (i.e. it is part of your model), you could create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

The content of your `init` / `update` methods would just set the class name for `element` based on what is returned by the `valueAccessor`.  For a simple example, you could do (using jQuery):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here

        $(element).addClass(valueAccessor());

    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever the associated observable changes value.
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.

    }
};
```

You might build a more complex binding based on the knockout [css binding](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings.js#L334).